# Are irrationals with an increasingly padded infinite series in the decimals non-algebraic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, transcendental-numbers

Are numbers such as this one non-algebraic (transcendental)?

The number starts: 0.05002500012500000625000...

It has an endless series of numbers, each term of which appears at ever increasing spacing in the digits.

I've used an infinite sum, algebraic numbers need to be able to be represented with a finite number of operations and cannot use infinite operations such as sums and products. However there may be an equivalent formula that uses only whats aloud for an algebraic number.

The full formula/number:

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F((2%5En)*(10%5E(n%5E2))),+n%3D1+to+infinity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2F((2%5En)*(10%5E(n%5E2))),%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity)

Comment: Interesting problem. The number of $0$'s does not climb nearly fast enough for a Liouville number argument.  And it does not look like $0.f(1)f(2)f(3)\cdots$ where $f$ is a non-constant polynomial, so it does not fall under the Mahler proof for the Champernowne (?) constant.

Comment: "algebraic numbers need to be able to be represented with a finite number of operations"  That's rather vague.  An algebraic number is a number $x$ that satisfies some equation of the form $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 = 0$ for some $a_n, a_{n-1}, \ldots, a_2, a_1, a_0 \in \mathbb Z$. $\qquad$

Comment: I should have mentioned that the operations must be hyper-operations or there inverses {+, -, *, /, etc...}, see this numberphile episode https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=seUU2bZtfgM I like your description but it's not that apparent to me why thats the case. They phrase it differently but it means the same thing, which is that using a finite number of these aloud operations and whole numbers, can you bring the number to 0. For example with x = 1/sqrt(5) then (1/x)^2 - 5 = 0 so 'x' is algebraic.

Comment: Why do you keep talking about **aloud** operations? Check a dictionary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number is $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} 10^{-n^2}$$
It's almost certainly transcendental, but I don't know if it's possible to prove that in the  current state of the art. Proving transcendence is notoriously difficult. I might note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n^2}$, which is essentially a Jacobi theta function evaluated at $1/10$, is known to be transcendental: see e.g.
[this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195510210) by
Daniel Duverney, Keiji Nishioka, Kumiko Nishioka, and Iekata Shiokawa.
It may be that the techniques of that paper could be applied to this problem: I haven't tried.

Comment: Nice answer :) TY